# How to give triggers to input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a inputfield and I need to give two trigger. One is **dropdown arrow** and Another is **cancel ("X")** image.  Here I am creating my inputfield.
My JS

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.className = 'styled-select';
        input.style = 'width:30%' ;
        input.id = "SearchInput";
        input.type = "text";
        input.title = "Madd";
        input.onclick = TableExpand; // This happening when I clicking on Inputfield
```

My CSS for Inputfield

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.styled-select {
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #95B8E7;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
   background: url(combo_arrow.png) no-repeat right white;
   position:relative;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   }

.styled-select select {
   background: transparent;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 100px;
   font-size: 11px;
   border: 0;
   height: 17px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   }
```

I need two trigger as I mentioned **Arrow and Cross**. I am able to give **arrow by using background image but don't know how to give Cross image.** 
Also How I will use this as a trigger. I mean When I click on Cross and Dropdown one it leads me to the one function where I can write my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the triggers as absolutely positioned elements on the input field. This way, you can add separate click events on these triggers to be able to perform whatever you want when they are clicked.

Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="textfield" />
  <div id="triggers">
    <img class="trigger" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/128/Stock%20Index%20Up.png" id="arrow" />
    <img class="trigger" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/musthave/128/Remove.png" id="cross" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

#textfield {
  height:30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.trigger{
  width: 20px;
}

#triggers {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#arrow").click(function() {
    $("#textfield").val("Arrow was clicked.");
  })
  $("#cross").click(function() {
    $("#textfield").val("Cross was clicked.");
  })
})
```

Here is a working version:
https://jsfiddle.net/1j760ztn/

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I am trying this as per my code and revert back to you. Also Is it possible by using only plain JS

Comment: If I am changing to 300px or some dynamic width, Still those buttons are there

Comment: Change the width of the container, not the input field. :) The container is meant to wrap around the input field and the triggers as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

Your cross and dropdown should be separate buttons. And the javascript you need to listen for them goes like this.

```
<input type="text" id="theText"><button id="cross"><button id="dropdown">

<script> var cross = document.getElementById('cross'); cross.addEventListener("click", function(){ document.getElementById('theText').innerHTML = 'clicked X' }); </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Admcfajn, These buttons I need to attach with my input field is it. Ya I am bit new in HTML so asking.

Comment: Np, yup `addEventListener` should get you going. Also, it's best to avoid using html-elements (input,div, etc...) as both javascript variable-names & html/css id's & classes. Sometimes it causes confusion, and other times it causes things to break.

Comment: Sure I am trying this.